# Render Graphics3D of anatomical data in color

Tags: graphics3d, color, curated-data, anatomy

I am trying to render a bone structure in color in *Mathematica* 10.3, but none of the obvious methods seem to work:

- `Graphics3D[{Blue, 
    Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFoot"]["Graphics3D"][[1]]}]`
- `Graphics3D[{Blue, (Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFoot"][
   "Graphics3D"])[[1]]}]`
- `Graphics3D[{Lighting -> {{"Point", 
   Blue, {0, 3, 5}}}, (Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFoot"][
   "Graphics3D"])[[1]]}]`

...and numerous `Directives` and such.

How do I color such a 3D model?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you peer at the `InputForm[]` of the result, you'll quickly find that the coloring scheme used for bones is something like this:

```
Graphics3D[{Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.35]},
                         {"Directional", GrayLevel[0.2], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]},
                         {"Directional", GrayLevel[0.2], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]},
                         {"Directional", GrayLevel[0.2], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}},
            Specularity[GrayLevel[0.5], 1.5], RGBColor[0.88, 0.847, 0.748],
            Sphere[]}]
```

[image: "bone"-colored sphere]

which is why the bones are not affected by your coloring attempts; these directives come directly before the primitives they're coloring.

---

On the other hand, the bones themselves are `GraphicsComplex[]` objects, so one can just extract them before coloring:

```
leftFootBones = Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFoot"]["Graphics3D"];

Graphics3D[{ColorData["Legacy", "Turquoise"], EdgeForm[], 
            Cases[leftFootBones, _GraphicsComplex, ∞]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: that was a weird color choice, admittedly.]